# How to send a newsletter in magento 1.9

Tags: newsletter

I have created a Newsletter template and place that in newsletter queue. But not sending newsletter in sender gmail address.
How to solve ?

Comment: have you checked cron ? make sure your cron is running to send the news letter. You may also check cron_schedule table to check the scheduled tasks status

Comment: check your email communication, whether it is enabled or not